# "Deleting" from array in C

Tags: c, string, struct

So I have a string array in a struct where I stored car plate numbers and I want to print those plate numbers (a plate number can occurs several times) which occur more than 1x (at least 2 times) to a file, but only once!

```
    typedef struct plates {
        char plate[10];
        char gate[25];
    } PL; //does not matter in this case

    PL r[50];
    int length = 50;
    char nullStr[5] = { '\0' };
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (strcmp(r[i].plate, r[j].plate) == 0) {
                strcpy(r[j].plate, nullStr);
                fprintf(f_out, "%s\n", r[i].plate);
            }
        }
    }
```

input: `ASD123, QWE123, ASD123, KKR332, ASD123, QWE123,`

output should be: `ASD123, QWE123`

but I get: `ASD123, ASD123, QWE123`

Comment: Please post the entire function, along with struct definitions.

Comment: You are printing every time you find a duplicate.  There are 3 copies of ASD123, so you print 2 of those for the 2 duplicates, and there are 2 copies of QWE123, so you print 1 of those for the 1 duplicate.

Comment: Do what you are doing, but do the printing in a separate loop after you have done what you are doing.

Comment: Also, by the i=2 iteration of the outer loop, you will now be looking at the empty string that was put there in the i=0 iteration, and think that it is a duplicate of the empty strings at j=4 and j=5 that were put there by the i=0 and i=1 iterations respectively.

Comment: You are not allowed to edit your question when you found a solution. instead please post your new answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Your outer loop considers *every* element of your array, including those that have already been found and printed as duplicates.  That's harmless when there are only two copies, but if there any further copies to find then you will print extras.</s>

Your inner loop prints *each* duplicate it finds, even if it has already printed the plate number.  Furthermore, your outer loop does not provide any special handling for empty strings copied into the array in earlier iterations, leaving your program prone to matching them with others, and printing them (as blank lines).

Overall, there are multiple ways you could approach the problem.  One would be to keep track of which plate numbers are dupes of one that has already been printed -- with an auxilliary array, for example -- and to abort the inner loop after handling one dupe.  Another way would be to modify the array as you go, say by setting the dupes to empty strings, and then ignoring empty strings when you later encounter them again.  That reuires you to not exit the inner loop early, but to keep track there of whether the present plate number has yet been printed, so as to avoid printing it multiple times.  A third would be to sort the array first, enabling you handle all copies of plate number as a single group because they will all be in adjacent positions of the array.

Comment: Well, the outer loop is not the problem; it will only encounter unique strings because the dups ahead will have been set to empty. (Consequently the possible exception is that multiple empty strings will be encountered, matched, deleted and printed over and over again, but that's harmless redundancy because it doesn't print anything.) The *inner* loop is the problem. I'd suggest to add a boolean in the outer loop which is set to true if and only if a dup has been found and suppresses output of additional dups (but does not suppress their deletion).

Comment: You are mostly right, @PeterA.Schneider, and I have updated this answer accordingly.  The outer loop is nevertheless a *bit* of a problem in the OP's implementation, however, in that under some circumstances it contributes to printing copies of `nullStr`, which will manifest as extra blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

The plate number is printed every time you find a copy, hence `ASD123` is printed twice because there are 3 occurrences.

Furthermore, modifying the array for this purpose is a bad side effect.

You could instead compute the number of copies of the plate number that are present before it in the array and only print those that have exactly one copy. in other words only print the first copy of any plate number:

```
typedef struct plates {
    char plate[10];
    char gate[25];
} PL; //does not matter in this case

PL r[50];
int length = 50;
// read the plate numbers, update length
for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    int copies = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (strcmp(r[i].plate, r[j].plate) == 0)
            copies++;
    }
    if (copies == 1)
        fprintf(f_out, "%s\n", r[i].plate);
}
```